# Trying to redirect using .htaccess any url that has index2 in it regardless of what comes after

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got legacy URLs like:

```
mysite.com/index2.php?option=com_mtree&task=print&link_id=383&Itemid=168
```

and I'd like to redirect any URL that has index2.php in it (regardless of what comes after index2.php) to `mysite.com/my-nice-url`

I've tried

```
RewriteRule ^index2(.+) /my-nice-url/and-more/ [l,r=301]
```

But that makes `/my-nice-url/and-more/?option=com_mtree&task=print&link_id=383&Itemid=168` which i don't want. Could anyone provide a bit of guidance please?

Comment: Wow thanks lanzz....why don't you just add that comment to very question asked at stackoverflow and stop anyone else being able to answer?

Comment: I don't see how my (apparently moderated-out already) comment is stopping anyone from answering your question. Not all questions asked on SO are plainly answered in the _very first_ place you should look, some people actually do have questions that are not answered by having somebody else read the manual instead of you. I believe my comment actually _did_ provide you with "a bit of guidance", exactly as you asked, but apparently you just wanted a ready answer that you could just use without any effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Rewrite rule pattern can only mathc **path** part of URL -- query string has to be matched separately (via RewriteCond)

2) By default, query string is passed to new URL if new URL does not has its' own query string. Solution -- provide empty query string (by adding `?` at the end of URL):

```
RewriteRule ^index2\.php$ /my-nice-url/and-more/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: What does the question mark on the end do? Thanks! It works a treat!!

Comment: It does exactly what I have described in #2 -- starts query string part. Since there is nothing after that -- it means **empty** query string.

Comment: Oh goodness sorry, i didn't read point 2. What a twit! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This should work, even if it's not exactly what you want:

```
RewriteRule ^/index2(.+)$ /my-nice-url/and-more/?
```

From the [rewriterule Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

> Note: Query String
>
> The Pattern will not be matched against the query string. Instead, you
>   must use a RewriteCond with the %{QUERY_STRING} variable. You can,
>   however, create URLs in the substitution string, containing a query
>   string part. Simply use a question mark inside the substitution
>   string, to indicate that the following text should be re-injected into
>   the query string. When you want to erase an existing query string, end
>   the substitution string with just a question mark. To combine a new
>   query string with an old one, use the [QSA] flag.